# Casting values of a map to their proper types in clojure

Tags: xml, clojure

I'm parsing a CSV file and since CSV has no type information, all values (floats, ints, dates, etc) become strings. To fix the types, I've created a map that defines each field's type. Now I need to convert the fields into the proper types.

Given a map where the values are strings containing integers and floats and possibly other types I need to return a map with those values converted to their proper types by referencing the type definition map. Below is a sample of the code I've come up with but, I feel there must be a better way to do this.

```
(mapv #(case ({"one" :int, "point-two" :float} (key %))
        :int {(key %) (Integer/parseInt (val %))}
        :float {(key %) (Float/parseFloat (val %))}
        {(key %) (val %)}) ; If there's no type defined, just return the original
 {"one" "1", "point-two" ".2", "three" "three"})
```

Is re-creating the map in each case result necessary, it seems like there should be a way to just modify the values, without touching the keys inside the `case`. Re-creating the map entry with `{(key %) (val %)}` for the default test seems even more awkward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce-kv` and `update-in`.

```
(def input {:a "1" :b "2.5" :c "more" :d "string" :e "keys"})

(def typetrans {:a #(Long/parseLong %) :b #(Double/parseDouble %)})

(reduce-kv #(update-in %1 [%2] %3) input typetrans)
; => {:a 1, :c "more", :b 2.5, :d "string", :e "keys"}
```

It only touches the keys which really have to be changed. Not the whole map.